# How to check that AES Matrix is MDS?

Tags: aes, mds

I want to understand how can I prove that M matrix in AES is MDS. I know that a matrix is MDS if every determinant of every square submatrix is different from 0.

I don't get this. How much submatrix does it have? If I swap rows or columns, does that change something? Do I have to calculate the determinant in a certain mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer focuses on the AES matrix only. In general, an $A$ matrix with all submatrices having full rank generates an MDS code when concatenated by an identity matrix of the right size to form $[I|A]$, but that's really a coding theory matter.

As to the specific question, this is basic linear algebra but you need to work over the field that AES is defined over. Let the $k\times k$ matrix (like the AES mixing matrix) be
$$A=\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\cdots&a_{1,k}\\
 \vdots &&& \vdots \\ 
a_{k,1}&a_{k,2}&\cdots&a_{k,k}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The $1\times1$ submatrices are all nonzero, they're just the entries of $A.$

The $2\times 2$ submatrices: choose any two rows or columns. you can also use the fact that the matrix is circulant to reduce the cases.

So the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{1,1}&a_{1,3}\\ 
a_{2,1}&a_{2,3}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

is the same matrix as
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{2,2}&a_{2,4}\\ 
a_{3,2}&a_{3,4}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and thus has the same determinant, etc.

The $4\times$ submatrix is the whole matrix.

Row and column swaps only change the sign of the determinant and can be ignored.

**Edit:** You need to use the finite field with 256 elements as explained in the link below.

[How to use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to invert a finite field element?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34212/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-to-invert-a-finite-field-element)

This is NOT mod 256 arithmetic.

Comment: thanks a lot. So, for example the only cases that i have to see is 2x2 (36 cases) and 3x3 (16 cases) but i can delete many cases?. AES field is 2^8. The only difference with common determinat math is that i have to calculate in modular 256?

Comment: sorry i forgot something. The cases that i enum. Are without row/colums swaps? or in all this cases, that i calculated with the another answer formule, consider swaps?. Sorry i m so new in this topic!!!

Comment: see my edit which clarifies this

Comment: thanks a lot kodlu. but i want to know if i understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Rijndael.27s_finite_field i have to define * and xor operationes and then use determinat formule? wich formula i have to use? with + and - or there is another? the mod is the polynomial?

Comment: The modulo operation is mod the polynomial as well as mod 2. And since you are operating mod 2, + and - are the same, addition mod 2, which is xor.

Comment: the last one, can you explain to me http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42764/how-to-find-the-aes-branch-number the algorithm thawt calculate the matrix, what formula use?

Comment: "The 1×1 submatrices are all nonzero" -- but MixColumn matrix has zero entries!

Comment: You're wrong, the matrix is a circulant matrix with first row $[2,3,1,1]$ expressed as integers, I don't see any zeroes!

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be $[n,k,d]$ code, where $n$,$k$ and $d$ are length of code words, dimension and minimum distance of code, respectively. Codes  with $n-k=d-1$ are called MDS codes.

In general case, if a $m\times m$ matrix $M$ is an MDS we can use $[I\mid M]$ as a generator matrix
and check if the code produced is MDS code. In this state, produced code $C$ is $[2m,m,d]$ code. So $d$ must be equal to $m+1$.

For a matrix of order $m$, by your mentioned method, you should obtain $\sum_{i=1}^m \, {m \choose i }^2$ determinant to find out that a matrix is MDS or not, but you can easily compute the minimum distance of codes with powerful programs such as MAGMA, for small $m$.

Comment: well, if i want to check all the codes. How can i do that? with one code for example?